# Как поддерживать соединение WebSockert при переходе между страницами сайта

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

есть сайт написанный на Django. Для работы с вебсокетами использовал библиотеку Django Channels. Проблема в том, что при переходе между страницами каждый раз происходит разрыв соединения и восстановление. Каким образом можно сохранять этот вебсокет соединение?

Comment: 1. никак. 2. Делать переход на страницу без перезагрузки страницы. То бишь загрузить контент другой страницы через `ajax` например или же на том же сокете.

Comment: как это никак? неужели нет способов?

Comment: Ну я же написал вторым вариантом.